# UserForm ListBox not accepting more than 10 elements? Run-time error '380'

Tags: excel, vba

Multi-Selectable Listbox on UserForm in Excel VBA is not correctly populating, past the tenth column.

I've explicitly set my column count as 13, my syntax seems appropriate.

I've read some other threads on this, only hints I get are a ListView item, that I can not seem to figure out how to get in to my toolbox.

```
Do While Not FetchSearch Is Nothing

                    FetchPositionVar = FetchSearch.Address

                    PossibleRecordsList.AddItem

                    ListPos = PossibleRecordsList.ListCount

                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 0) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 19).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 1) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 7).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 2) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 8).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 3) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 10).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 4) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 11).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 5) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 12).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 6) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 1).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 7) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 2).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 8) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 4).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 9) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 5).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 10) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 6).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 11) = Trim(ws.Cells(FetchSearch.Row, 15).Value)
                    PossibleRecordsList.List(ListPos - 1, 12) = RecordYear

                    Set FetchSearch = FetchRange.Find(what:=FetchDataMatch, After:=Range(FetchPositionVar), SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookAt:=xlPart)

                    If FirstFindPositionVar = FetchSearch.Address Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
```

I am populating a multi-selection ListBox from multiple worksheets.
Each list item, is an array with 13 elements, drawn from a row on one of the worksheets, after a search identifies the row with relevant data to display.

The list will hold several "possibly correct records" that are then displayed for the user to multi-select.  Selected records are bumped into a different list, and used for a report generation.

when it reaches the 11th element, I get run time error 380

Comment: You can only use 10 columns if you populate with `additem`. Use an array assigned to the List property, or the Rowsource property with a range address.

Comment: See if [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140999/23788) helps

Comment: forgive me, but i don't understand either cryptic response.  

MG  - the code page has no comments, and as far as I can tell is just referencing the same points for all versions.
rory . . . I think rowsource doesn't work for me, because my elements are not in the same order as they appear in the raw data row. And I thought I was using an array assigned to the list? I mean each list item is supposed to be an array of 13 elements.

I'm trying to create an array, to add to a list of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sub to initialize a listbox with the right number of columns. Use it only if you’re not initialize your listbox yourself with `Listbox.List`, or run the sub before your `Listbox.List`.

```
'Force a listbox to initialize with the right number of columns
Public Sub InitializeListBox(ColumnsNum As Byte, ListData As MSForms.ListBox)
    Dim cols As Byte
    cols = ColumnsNum - 1
    
    ReDim arrInit(0 To 0, 0 To cols)
    ListData.List = arrInit
    
    'Delete the first empty item introduced by arrInit
    ListData.RemoveItem 0
    
End Sub
```

Say your listbox is named `lst_data`, you could do something like this to initialize it during `UserForm_Initialize()` event.

```
Const colsCount as byte = 5

With Me.lst_data
    .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
    .ColumnCount = colsCount 
    .ColumnWidths = colWidths
    .IntegralHeight = False
    .Locked = False
    .Enabled = True
    .ColumnHeads = False
End With

'Required to force listbox array to contain the right number of columns
InitializeListBox colsCount, Me.lst_data
```

You can add more than 10 columns with this method because `.List` is initialized with an array.